# How to match a sequence of characters not preceded by specific character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a series of numbers in my string, and I want to select them with RegEx. Though, if a certain sequence of numbers are preceded by '`@`' character(without quotations), then it should skip it. I do not know how should I solve it in Javascript.

I know I should use Lookahead to check the condition:
`(?!@[a-z])`
But the above rule is used only to NOT select the numbers preceded by @, what about selecting those which are not preceded by `@`? I need to say to RegEx to skip `@\d` and rather select only `(?!@\d)`. How should I do this?

For instance I have this string:

```
helloMrRobert5555AndGoodByeMrSteve@8888
```

Expected output:

```
5555
```

Comment: an example along with expected output.

Comment: here's the power of alternation operator `@\d|(\d)` ......... or `@\d+|(\d+)`

Comment: As @AvinashRaj: says use `/@\d+|(\d+)/g` and use captured group #1

Comment: negative look behind `(?<![@\d])(\d+)`

Comment: @AruneshSingh: No, JS does not support look-behind.

Comment: You are trying to match numbers that are not proceeded by a ``@`` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple regex like this (if the length of number is fixed):

```
/[^@](\d{4})/g
```

And use substitution `$1`.

If the length is not fixed use `/@\d+|(\d+)/g`.

Comment: The only correct answer is `@\d+|(\d+)`, and it was Avinash Raj who suggested that.